# UIImagePickerController pixelated image from choosing too quickly, before image fully loaded

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, pixelate

I am using UIImagePickerController in an iOS app to save an image in context using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions.

I recently noticed that I picture I had saved and then displayed at a later date was highly pixelated; when I went back with the same code and imported the photo again, I got a great image. After playing with this for a while on my device, I figured out that the quality of the image saved depends on WHEN I pressed the 'Choose' button on the 'Move and Scale' screen.

If the image is a larger image and still loading when I press the button, the image is pixelated... if I wait until the image loads, it is fine. My question is, is there any way I can control when the user presses the 'Choose' button - is there any way to force them to wait until after the image is fully loaded? Or is there another way that would be better to approach this issue?

```
- (void)choosePhoto {

    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage *pickedImage = (UIImage*)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    [self setPersonImage:pickedImage];
}


- (void) setPersonImage:(UIImage *)pickedImage  {

    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] managedObjectContext];
    PersonImage *oldImage = person.image;
    if (oldImage != nil) {
        [context deleteObject:(NSManagedObject*)oldImage];
    }

    if (pickedImage != nil) {
        // Create an image object for the new image.
        PersonImage *newImageObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PersonImage" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newImageObject setImage:pickedImage]; 
        [person setImage:newImageObject]; 
    }
    else {
        [person setImage:nil];
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you saving an image from your app to the Photos app? Are you displaying the image using a WebView/UiImageView ?

Comment: The user selects an image from their photo album or takes a photo. I save a thumbnail and then I save the data for the full image (up to a maximum resolution) both through core-data, the latter using BLOB and imageToDataTransformer. Later on, I use the full-size image to display in various places/sizes. I know it is not recommended to save in Core Data, but it is what it is for now. Just thinking about the problem at hand with the pixelation.

Comment: I have the same problem. Noticed that image is returned is not a full-size image, but a thumbnail sized 90x120.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you implement your own Crop&Resize view controller.

1. set `imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO`.
2. create your view controller in `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` and pass selected image to your view controller.
3. push your view controller to image picker: `[picker pushViewController:yourVC animated:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

The image captured by the iPhone 4 camera is ~5 MB in size and it takes a while to display/render it. One option is to compress the image using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`.

If you do not want to compress the image, you can use UIWebView to display the images. The `UIWebViewDelegate` has a method `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`, that hits after the rendering has been completed. You can enable the choose button in this method (which is disabled initially).

Comment: Hmm, okay, thanks. So there is nothing for the image picker as delivered? I have everything else working perfectly and don't really want to mess with it at this point! I will do it if I have to, but it seems like there should be a way to intercept this without changing the method of capture itself if it is *basically* working for me.

Comment: Maybe if I put the save method on a time delay after the button is pressed? Just not sure of how long that would be, I guess that is the problem with that approach. The delay can't be too short or too long. So unless I can get some sort of delegate method that won't work..

Comment: The method of capture is not being altered. You will compress the image after it has been delivered to you in didFinishPickingMedia..

Comment: I think the problem is that the incomplete image is being delivered in didFinishPickingMedia because the Choose button is pressed too soom..

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Can you post your code related to saving the image?